# Get image from Backend folder and display it in frontend (React and Node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, display

i have an upload method that store my image in a folder in backend. I'm trying to display it in the frontend but it says to me that it can't accomplish my request becouse folder is out of src. How can i avoid this issue?

Is there any kind of method that allow me to access to the path of that folder?
I'm using react and node js.

Comment: Either store the image in a public folder or any cloud provider like s3

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve static files with express, [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) explains how to do that.

I hope that it works for you!